# Javascript getElementsByTagName not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add a Open Graph tag to a website using the following JavaScript code, I need to add the open graph tags before the closing of the `<head>` but the code is not working and the open graph tags are not being added.

```
var newtext = document.createTextNode(" <meta property='og:type'   content='article' /> ");
var x=getElementsByTagName("head")[0]
x.appendChild(newtext);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't add a meta property in javascript : this tag is usually interpreted by bot or engines who don't care about interpreting your scripts. That's the case for the Open Grap tags : they must be added statically.

Comment: Yes, but add them in your HTML (or PHP, or whatever) page, not in javascript. Facebook's crawler won't execute the javascript to find your meta tag.

Comment: is there a way to write the data to the webpage using a javascript document.write perhaps other than putting it there manually?

Comment: No. This must be in the header of the page read by the crawler. If it really needs to be generated, that must be server side (PHP, JSP, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Use `var x=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]`, and it should work.

Working code:

```
var metaTag = document.createElement("meta");
metaTag.setAttribute("property", "og:type");
metaTag.setAttribute("content", "article");
var x=document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
x.appendChild(metaTag);
```